# How to put check box and button in linear layout side by side in Android?

Tags: android

This my code what I have written :

```
while (i.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry me= (Map.Entry) i.next();
        checkBox=new CheckBox(this.getActivity());
        checkBox.setId(Integer.parseInt(me.getKey().toString()));
        checkBox.setText(me.getValue().toString());
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(checkBox));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) linearMain.getLayoutParams();
        params.width=250;
        linearMain.addView(checkBox);
        dltButton=new Button(this.getActivity());
        dltButton.setTag(btnCounter);
        btnCounter++;
        dltButton.setText("Delete");
        linearMain.addView(dltButton);


    }
```

and the screen is like this.
[image: This is the screen]

I want one check box and one delete button side by side and next in the next row similar way.
How to implement it any idea?

Answer (score 0):

ok try this, Ihave modified your code to basic logic.you Activity's layout file should be as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout >
```

and then you activity should be

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout mainContainer;

CheckBox checkBox;
Button dltButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContainer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){

        checkBox=new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.setText("Text");

        LinearLayout linearMain = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearMain.setWeightSum(1.0f);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams half = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);

        linearMain.addView(checkBox, half);

        dltButton=new Button(this);
        dltButton.setTag("tag");
        dltButton.setText("ffff");
        linearMain.addView(dltButton, half);

        mainContainer.addView(linearMain);



    }
```

}

Comment: Comment out linearMain.removeAllViews(); line and make this the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    String[] count = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };

    int checkbox_count = 3;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    for (int i = 0; i < checkbox_count; i++) {
        LinearLayout horizontal_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        horizontal_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontal_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 80));
        checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.setText("checkbox " + count[i]);
        horizontal_layout.addView(checkBox);
        Button delete_btn = new Button(this);
        delete_btn.setText("Delete");
        horizontal_layout.addView(delete_btn);
        layout.addView(horizontal_layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: The layout at R.id.linear_layout is just a simple Linear Layout